# If Statement in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the problem:

I have multiple membership levels and per account the user gets displayed a different price amount for the product. Although, throughout the whole project its all SQL Query's for the price and it's too much to change.

Is there a way where I can call the current user id in the MYSQL database that the person is logged into and lets say they Gold Member they get 
price * .50 = (their new product price)
silver member: price * .75

Now based on their account, the price gets multiplied and product_price will now return that new amount instead of the default $100 lets say.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the `IF()` function or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: I know that, but I mean where would I put it. Im using Sequel Pro

Comment: Sequel Pro is for running SQL queries by hand, it has nothing to do with running queries from a PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE member_level
        WHEN 'gold' THEN price * 0.50
        WHEN 'silver' THEN price * 0.75
        ELSE price
       END AS discounted_price
FROM ...
```

Comment: Barmar strikes again.  Excellent answer!

Comment: How can I get the current user id. I have a query I use $this->session->user_id

Comment: Bind it as a parameter to the prepared statement, just like getting any other variable into a query.

Comment: In the mySQL or in the actual project?

Comment: or Is there an option to automatically get the session while writing this SELECT CASE in the MySQL?

Comment: It's in the PHP script. Don't you know how to put PHP variables into MySQL queries? What's different about this case?

Comment: I mean I have a users table. membership table. and products. A user gets assigned a membership level 1-4 upon sign up, and then on the products I need to extract the current user thats Logged in, and then do that Case statement you showed. My question is how do I add in the current user signed in

Answer (score 0):

If you have member level in that query you can use case:

```
select case when ?member_level='gold' then price * .50 else price end as final_price from products
```